# Ruby, Rails, and Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, windows-7, ruby-on-rails

Just wanted to know if anyone out there has had the same difficulty as I have - I've done a vanilla install of Ruby 1.9.1 using the windows installer, with only a couple of gems:

```
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
bson (1.0.3)
jnunemaker-validatable (1.8.4)
mongo (1.0.3)
mongo_mapper (0.8.2)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
plucky (0.3.2)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
```

On a frequent basis, when a page is requested, WEBrick starts spitting out Segmentation Faults, or the Ruby runtime just packs it in altogether ("... has stopped working").

I've tried the same setup with the 1.8.7 installer with the same result. I *really* want to do some dev with Rails, but this is beyond a pain in the ass, and isn't really helping its cause.

PS: I'm a relative n00b to the land of Ruby/Rails, so if it's something really obvious that I've missed in the setup, be gentle :)

Comment: A lot of Ruby and Rails pieces still don't play well with Windows... I have tried multiple times b/c it seems like it "should" work, but it only goes so far until something breaks. I would highly recommend installing Cygwin and doing all your Rails work there, where nearly everything should just work the way it's supposed to.

Comment: I have no problem using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2 on Win 7 x64, and MySQL|SQLite. So it definitely works, except that some things are REALLY slow (Spork helped a bit, but installing it was another adventure). But be prepared to use Google search often for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the version of MySQL you're using?

The mysql gem you've installed is sensible (and specific) to a version of MySQL. That is because libMySQL.dll, the library that the gem uses to connect to MySQL introduced incompatible changes between the versions.

You can read more about that here:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2009/08/21/mysqlruby-2-8-1-released/

And also in the tutorials of RubyInstaller project:

http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/tutorials

I would personally recommend use Ruby 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.1, as the issues you may encounter with 1.9.1 will be higher than 1.8.7

Hope that helps.

Comment: Before moving back to 1.8.7 I would try 1.9.2 http://rubyinstaller.org/news/2010/08/23/rubyinstaller-1-9-2-p0-and-new-devkits-released/